# Get child element distance from parent top

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Child distance from top parent]

Let's say I have an `<li>` element inside a scrollable div and the scroll was set to show that element in the viewport.

I need to get the distance between that element and its scrollable parent, as shown in the picture above, but both `element.getBoundingClientRect().top` and `element.offsetTop` give me the wrong values. Can that be done?

I made a pen, to make things a little bit easier:

http://codepen.io/Darksoulsong/pen/LbYMex

A piece of my code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var selectedEl = document.getElementById('consequatur-51');
  var selectedElRect = selectedEl.getBoundingClientRect();
  var sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');  
  sidebar.scrollTop = selectedEl.offsetTop - 60;

  document.getElementById('offsetTop').innerText = selectedEl.offsetTop;
  document.getElementById('rectTop').innerText = selectedElRect.top;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to make it work. Actually, @Dummy's answer gave me some important insights.

Basically, the formulae is:

```
childElementDistanceFromParentTop = actualChildElementDistancefromTop - parentElementDistanceFromTop
```

With these coordinates I can even tell if the element is visible in the viewport or not.

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/Darksoulsong/pen/rWawrZ

Answer (score 3):

```
var parentTop = parentElem.getBoundingClientRect().top; // Initial parent's top distance from the top of the viewport;

var currentChildTop = childElement.getBoundingClientRect().top; // Initial child's top distance from the top of the viewport;
```

If you do `var childParentDistance = Math.abs(parentTop - currentChildTop)`, you will get the initial distance between the child element and its parent. But as you scroll, you need to account for the scroll amount. Like this

```
var scrolledParentDistance= Math.abs(parentTop - parentElem.getBoundingClientRect().top);
```

and if you subtract `scrolledParentDistance` from `childParentDistance`, you will get the new distance between this child and its parent

Comment: Your `scrolledParentDistance` will always be 0.

Comment: No. If you have scrollable element, its `top` will change as you scroll the content inside. so as you scroll `getBoundingClientRect().top` will change as well. Just so you know `getBoundingClientRect().top` returns the distance from the top of the element to the top of the viewport at the current point in time, it is not a fixed value

Comment: Well, you defined `parentTop = parentElem.getBoundingClientRect().top`, and then  `parentTop - parentElem.getBoundingClientRect().top` is basically `parentTop - parentTop`, so `0`.

Comment: If you create a test scrollable element, and run that code, it will return a non-zero value as long as the content is scrolled. The `parentTop = parentElem.getBoundingClientRect().top` will cache the "actual" `top` distance of this parent element when it is not scrolled, then `parentElem.getBoundingClientRect().top` will return the new `top` distance of the parent element relative to the top of the viewport assuming that it was scrolled. Just to point out that if you have a scrollable element, its `scrollHeight` will be larger than its `clientHeight`

Comment: I just tested here. `scrolledParentDistance` is always 0.

Comment: @darksoulsong I am currently working on app which has an image panel with multiple images inside, when I scrolled the content inside, called `getBoundingClientRect().top` on the image panel in Chrome Developer console, it returned different values.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation, and I guess one of the missing parts was the distance that a human observer does not see; as scrollable containers usually hide their overflowing content. Hence I felt adding my answer may be useful, with a little example.

Find a way to programmatically scroll a **parent** element that hides content which overflows it and has:

```
position: fixed;
top: whateveryouwant;
height: 80%;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

in a way such that a specific **child**'s top border is aligned with your **parent**'s top.

With the CSS above you have a **parent** div which always fills 80% of your screen's height, with a `getBoundingClientRect().top` value which thus always stays the same for a given device.

You then need to build a formula where you can use **parent**.scrollTo(0,`outputOfFormula`); to scroll the **parent** in a way such that the targeted **child**'s top is aligned with your **parent**'s top.
@TrashCan was actually almost there, and he / she was right that what's missing is that you have to consider the amount by which the parent scrolled, to account for all possible cases. So all in all you have something like this:

```
------------------------------------ Viewport's Top


------------------------------------ Popup (Parent)'s Top
|                                  |
|     ---                          | Horizontal Level of Targeted Child's Top
|                                  |
|                                  |
------------------------------------ Popup (Parent)'s Bottom 


------------------------------------ Viewport's Bottom
```

Which gives you:

1. d(Viewport's Top - Horizontal Level of Targeted Child's Top) = **child**.getBoundingClientRect().top
2. d(Viewport's Top - Popup (Parent)'s Top) = **parent**.getBoundingClientRect().top
3. d(Popup (Parent)'s Top - Horizontal Level of Targeted Child's Top) = d1 - d2

If you count the pixels on your screen that separate your **parent**'s top form your **child**'s top, you now get exactly `d3`. But `d3` may not be the correct value to use to scroll down your **parent** to display the **child** at its top. If your Popup has already been scrolled down, `d3` only represents a part of the actual distance of your **parent**'s top to your **child**'s top. Your child may actually be situated much much lower inside your Popup, so you'd be missing all of that distance needed to be scrolled down too. To thus complete the formula and get the actual distance we have to scroll our **parent** to display our **child** within its top, we have to add **parent**.[scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) to `d3`. If we did not scroll the parent by any pixel, the `scrollTop` property will simply be 0.

Hence for this scenario, you need to use:

**child**.getBoundingClientRect().top - **parent**.getBoundingClientRect().top + **parent**.scrollTop

and then do

**parent**.scrollTo(0,result)

and you're covered for all cases of this scenario.